# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BullExplorer

Tags: nestjs

When I run the Nestjs server, I get the following error. I am using the NestJS BullModule.

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the
> `BullExplorer (?, DiscoveryService, BullMetadataAccessor, MetadataScanner)` Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index [0] is available in the BullModule context.

> Potential solutions:
>
> - If ModuleRef is a provider, is it part of the current BullModule?
> - If ModuleRef is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within BullModule?
>   `@Module({ imports: [ /* the Module containing ModuleRef */ ] })`

Here is the Bull module configuration:

```
    BullModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
    const redisConfig = configService.get<RedisConfig>("redis");
    return {
      redis: {
        host: redisConfig.host,
        port: redisConfig.port,
      },
      defaultJobOptions: {
        timeout: 30000,
        removeOnComplete: true,
        removeOnFail: true,
        attempts: 3,
      },
    };
  },
  inject: [ConfigService],
}),
BullModule.registerQueue({
  name: MAIL_QUEUE,
}),
```

Comment: What are the `@nestjs/` packages and versions you're using?

Comment: Main ones are: "@nestjs/bull": "^0.4.1",    "@nestjs/common": "8.0.11",   "@nestjs/config": "1.0.2",   "@nestjs/core": "8.0.11",    "@nestjs/graphql": "9.0.5",

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the problem is known in NestJS community. There is a whole thread on their discord [here](https://discord.com/channels/520622812742811698/896062523302879262) and PR to the documentation, mentioning how to fix the problem, waiting for merging [here](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/pull/2152/files#diff-dbfd09994618eb01ebae6e105c74e97ba1ccb1cb3f0838a27dfb97effca9ca49R28-R80). Long story short, if you're working in monorepo setup with yarn workspaces, you don't want to hoist your `@nestjs` dependencies. Configure this in your root level `package.json` like this:

```json
{
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [],
    "nohoist": [
      "**/@nestjs/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this. But I am comfortable using 'pnpm' now. It is very fast and pretty stable.

I really liked this feature: pnpm installs a dependency only once. That way my project can share dependencies. If you depend on different versions of the dependency, only the files that differ are added to the store.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with how yarn workspaces work... my monorepo did not work properly when the Nestjs Bull module was installed in it using yarn v. 1.18.0.

My Original Answer:
Upgraded the yarn from 1.18.0 to 1.22.15

Edited Answer:
After deleting the node_modules folders, and doing the fresh install using yarn 1.22.15.. I bumped into the same error message again.

Finally, I decided to use pnpm workspaces and the new setup worked like a charm.

Hope someone may find it useful.